# Is "when" a conjunction in "I'll believe it when I see it."

Tags: conditional-constructions, parts-of-speech, conjunctions

I'm asking this question because if I remove the word "when" I get two sentences that can stand on their own 1. I'll believe it. 2. I see it.
I suppose in such cases "when" functions as a conjunction. I'm not exactly sure, though. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/162576/a-relative-adverb-or-a-conjunction-or-both

Comment: Some grammars take "when" to be a preposition, others a subordinator. Whichever interpretation is preferred, the expression "when I see it" is a temporal adjunct. Finite clauses, notably content clauses like "I see it" can usually stand alone, cf. also "[I left London] before [he arrived]"; "[I heard a rumour] that [the head is leaving next year]"; "[I don't know] whether [he accepted the offer]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, "when" is indeed a conjunction in your example because it connects two related ideas.

In fact, "when" is used as a conjunction rather often and in a variety of circumstances. Have a look at its entry in the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/when) for more definitions and examples.

Answer (score 1):

I'll believe it when I see it.

You are right; the word "when" is a conjunction. There are two clauses i.e. the main clause "I'll see it" and the subordinate or dependent clause introduced by when "when l see it".  The subordinate conjunction when  joins the two clauses.